# Python list index from a certain point onwards

Tags: python, list, indexing

For a list

> a= [1,2,5,3,7,2,3,1,7,4,2,3,4,2,1]

i know that if i do this

> a.index(2)
>   1

However I want want to know what is the cleanest way to find a number from a certain point.

> a.index(2,from point 2)
>   5

Comment: what is a "point"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: he means index I guess..

Comment: You'll note: `a.index(2, 2)` results in `5`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via implementation of `list.index`, you can pass your "point" to achieve your desired output:

```
a= [1,2,5,3,7,2,3,1,7,4,2,3,4,2,1]
print(a.index(2, 2))
```

Output:

```
5
```

However, another possible solution is to built a dictionary:

```
val = 2
a= [1,2,5,3,7,2,3,1,7,4,2,3,4,2,1]
locations = dict(enumerate([i for i, c in enumerate(a) if c == val], start=1))
print(locations.get(2, False))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Is there a way with index or dictionaries for it to give a false if it does not find it instead of throwing an error

Comment: @Asilver I added the use of `dict.get` which accepts a second parameter, in this case `False`, to be returned if the key value is not found.

Answer (score 4):

The [`list.index` *[doc]*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) function has extra parameters:

> ```
> list.index(x[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is `x`. Raises a `ValueError` if there is no such item.
>
> The **optional arguments `start` and `end` are interpreted as in the slice notation** and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the `start` argument.

So you can use:

```
a.index(2, 2)
```

to **start searching from index 2** (including index 2).